# Understanding deep cutoff in Alpha–beta pruning algorithm

Tags: minimax

I am studying the Alpha Beta pruning algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning).

```
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, maximizingPlayer) is
if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node then
    return the heuristic value of node
if maximizingPlayer then
    value := −∞
    for each child of node do
        value := max(value, alphabeta(child, depth − 1, α, β, FALSE))
        α := max(α, value)
        if α ≥ β then
            break (* β cutoff *)
    return value
else
    value := +∞
    for each child of node do
        value := min(value, alphabeta(child, depth − 1, α, β, TRUE))
        β := min(β, value)
        if β ≤ α then
            break (* α cutoff *)
    return value
```

In this [slide](https://homepage.iis.sinica.edu.tw/%7Etshsu/tcg/2013/slides/slide7.pdf) (pg. 13) I read:

> Deep alpha cut-off: . Def: For a node u in a tree and a positive
> integer g, Ancestor(g, u) is the direct ancestor of u by tracing the
> parent’s link g times. . When the lower bound Vl is produced at and
> propagated from u’s great grand parent, i.e., Ancestor(3,u), or any
> Ancestor(2i + 1,u), i ≥ 1. . When an upper bound Vu is returned from
> the a branch of u and Vl ≥ Vu, then there is no need to evaluate all
> later branches of u.

Also [here](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Beta-Cutoff) the difference bteween shallow and deep cutoff.

I understand shallow alpha cutoff but I don't understand why deep alpha cutoff works.

UPDATE: I understood the deep cut watching this video:

[Animation of deep pruning by the Alpha-Beta Algorithm.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eychv62adsI)